# Comparing datasources or cell values of each sheet with another spraedsheet sheet ejs

Tags: compare, cell, spreadsheet, syncfusion

I am new to this. I am displaying spreadsheets using EJ spreadsheets sheet js. I want to compare "each of all sheets in one spreadsheet" with another. Can anyone provide me a solution using normal JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement can be achievable by comparing the strigified “dataSource” property which is retrived from the sheet object. Here the data is binded to the spreadsheet using dataSource property and compared the datasource of two spreadsheets in a button click event.

You can try with in working code example below or you can refer the sample
http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/2pd3dmtq

```
 <button id ="btn" onclick="onClick()">Click To Compare</button>
<h2> Spreadsheet1</h2>
<div id="Spreadsheet1"></div> 
<h2>Spreadsheet2</h2>
<div id="Spreadsheet2"></div>

<script>
    datasource = [
            { OrderID: 10001, CustomerID: "VINET", Freight: 12.256, Load: 123456 },
            { OrderID: 10002, CustomerID: "TOMSP", Freight: 23.3, Load: 1234 },
            { OrderID: 10003, CustomerID: "HANAR", Freight: 12.256, Load: 123456 },
            { OrderID: 10004, CustomerID: "VICTE", Freight: 23.3, Load: 1234 },
            { OrderID: 10005, CustomerID: "SUPRD", Freight: 12.256, Load: 123456 },
            { OrderID: 10006, CustomerID: "CHOPS", Freight: 23.3, Load: 1234 },
    ];

  datasource1 = [
            { OrderID: 10001, CustomerID: "VINET", Freight: 12.256, Load: 123456 },
            { OrderID: 10002, CustomerID: "TOMSP", Freight: 23.3, Load: 1234 },
            { OrderID: 10003, CustomerID: "HANAR", Freight: 12.256, Load: 123456 },
            { OrderID: 10004, CustomerID: "VICTE", Freight: 23.3, Load: 1234 },
            { OrderID: 10005, CustomerID: "SUPRD", Freight: 12.256, Load: 123456 },
            { OrderID: 10006, CustomerID: "CHOPS", Freight: 23.3, Load: 1234 }]

    $(function () {
        $("#Spreadsheet1").ejSpreadsheet({
            showRibbon: false,
          allowFormulaBar: false,
            columnWidth: 100,
            sheets: [{
                dataSource: window.datasource // Bind data for sheets using dataSource property
            }
           ],
        });
       $("#Spreadsheet2").ejSpreadsheet({
            showRibbon: false,
            columnWidth: 100,
         allowFormulaBar: false,
            sheets: [{
                dataSource: window.datasource1 // Bind data for sheets using dataSource property
            }],
        });
    });

    function onClick(args) {
        var ssObj1 = $("#Spreadsheet1").data("ejSpreadsheet"), ssObj2 = $("#Spreadsheet2").data("ejSpreadsheet"),
            sheet1ActIdx = ssObj1.getActiveSheetIndex(),sheet2ActIdx = ssObj2.getActiveSheetIndex(),
            sheet1DataSrc = ssObj1.getSheet(sheet1ActIdx).dataSource, // To access the datasource by passing the sheetIndex 
            sheet2DataSrc = ssObj2.getSheet(sheet2ActIdx).dataSource; 
        alert("The Datasource for Spreadsheet1 and Spreadsheet2 are " + (JSON.stringify(sheet1DataSrc) == JSON.stringify(sheet2DataSrc) ? "same":  "different"));
    }
</script>
```

Could you please check the sample and let us know whether it fulfills your requirement or not.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for improper question..I am uploading xlsx file and there is no key "datasource" for ssObj1.getSheet(sheet1ActIdx).dataSource . I tried convertind into JSON like ssObj1.saveAsJson(); but entire sheet's cell values in dataConatiner[sharedData] and rowCount colCount Sheets info are in model obj..dont know how to compare that saveAsJson obj.